# problem in passing the values in popviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
{    

 seViewController *seView = [[[seViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"seViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:seView animated:YES]; 
[seView insert:myString];}
```

I am passing the **seView** in pushViewController its working correctly. But how to pass the **seView** in **popViewController.**

Comment: Just a small coding tip: it is not common to start classes with a lowercase. Use uppercase instead to make it more readable for your fellow programmers.

Comment: @aravindanarvi you can use this code and where you want you view to be pop out write:-[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: i am not getting you, do you want to send the a value to the popped up `UIViewController` which will be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> ```
> popViewControllerAnimated:
> ```
>
> Pops the top view controller from the
>   navigation stack and updates the
>   display.
>
> ```
> - (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> animated
>
> ```
> Set this value to YES to animate the transition. Pass NO if you are
> ```
>
> setting up a navigation controller
>   before its view is displayed.
>
> Return Value
>
> The view controller that was popped
>   from the stack. Discussion
>
> **This method removes the top view controller from the stack and makes
>   the new top of the stack the active
>   view controller. If the view
>   controller at the top of the stack is
>   the root view controller, this method
>   does nothing. In other words, you
>   cannot pop the last item on the
>   stack.**
>
> In addition to displaying the view
>   associated with the new view
>   controller at the top of the stack,
>   this method also updates the
>   navigation bar and tool bar
>   accordingly. In iOS 3.0 and later, the
>   contents of the built-in navigation
>   toolbar are updated to reflect the
>   toolbar items of the new view
>   controller.

Comment: Aravind, to elaborate on the above, you may never need to call popViewController.  The navigation controller automatically pops the current view controller when the user hits the Back Button in the navigation bar.  You may not need to pop the view controller any other time.